# Limiting the size of browser's local storage

Tags: firefox, browser, local-storage

Modern browsers offer local storage to websites. Some websites use a very small amount of storage. But other websites seem to think that my local computer shall be their playground. Slack for example appears to consume 600MB in local data.

How can I limit the size of the local storage offered to a website when browsing with Firefox?

I am using Firefox 68.0.1. In about:preferences, the `Manage Cookies and Site Data` screen allows me to *remove* data but does not offer any method to allow me, the user, to assign a maximum total size limit nor a size limit per site. When searching, I found [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) which describes how Firefox uses my own hard drive size to determine local data sizes. However, it doesn't appear to offer any configuration instructions.

Comment: Over 3 years later, I'm also looking for a solution to this problem.